# How to make users images not blurred no matter what size photos are uploaded?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

A website is being built to allow users to upload photos they want!
But I found that when users upload some pictures of strange size, such as: slim pictures, because I set object-fill:cover in the img tag; this type of pictures will become a bit blurry

Is there a clear way to solve whether it can be set in CSS or through javaScript to allow users to upload photos of any size?

PS. The back-end engineer compresses pictures for website SEO, so the URL of each picture has amp;size=0.1. I have a root back-end saying that size=0.2 so that the picture will be normal, but for the time being for SEO Do not make such changes, I hope to find a solution here.

```css
.photo{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border-radius:10px;
    object-fit:cover;
  }
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <img class="photo" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/casual-guy-picture-id1007179332?k=6&m=1007179332&s=612x612&w=0&h=fnB0RWmkhdo92YX9pBKhEpKlq_oA83zz5HfQCqwgLyQ=" alt="">
</div>

<!-- If the uploaded image is of this weird size, it will appear blurred-->

<div class="demo">
  <img class="photo" src="https://upload.cc/i1/2021/06/23/CAjz7O.png" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: If your back-end is compressing elements, then it's possible that it's made blurry because of quality loss. Try using original file that does not come from your back-end. When covering element and image is zoomed it's possible for it to be pixelated

Comment: Is ontain rather than cover useful here? It at least guarantees the user will see the whole of their photo.

Comment: Relevant: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Comment: `object-fit:cover` does not change the *aspect* but will change the resolution.   It used to be that browsers (especially IE6 era) were *really bad* at resizing images.  I mean, **really bad**, perhaps they're better now, but probably still not as good as doing so with the correct options on the server - so it was always best to resize the image on the server to the size you want.   If you know you want a 70x70 thumbnail, then resize it in back-end and store that as your thumbnail / preview.